# Mindstorms EV3 Path-Finding Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, lego-mindstorms

I'm trying to find a way to write a path-finding algorithm for the Lego Mindstorms ev3 using Python (EV3DEV).

I am allowed to use the following sensors:
-Touch
-Gyro
-Ultrasonic
-Color

I want it to run through a "corridor" where it may hit a wall and it has to turn left or right (depending if there is room).
How would I use the sensors to determine if it should turn left or right? (and not end up going backwards)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of ports left on your robot, I would configure your robot as below[image]. Here is a high level example of how I would go about the algorithm

```
while True:
    if touch_pressed:
        drive backwards
        if right_ultra1 and right ultra2 clear:
            turnRight()
        else:
            turnLeft()
    drive_forward
```

Basically the robot drives forward until it hits on object. Then it backs up just enough to make a turn without hitting the wall. Next, it checks the sensors. Since the sensors are positioned to be as close to the length of the robot as possible, the narrowness of the passage can be estimated. If both sensors read an arbitrarily large value, the passage is wide enough else, the passage is not wide enough. After turning/if sensor was not pressed, it drives forward. Hope this helps!